# How to reinitialize label after directory chooser was used?

Tags: install4j

Today I created a customized directory chooser scrren with a directory chosser component and a label displaying the free disk space. The label has an initialization script which calculate the free disk space and set the value to the label. also the "Reset initialization..." checkbox is selected. That works fine if I go step back and return to my custom screen. But if I select a directory with the directory chooser the label is not reinitialized. For the chosser component I implemented a validation script and the first action at this script ist to call `formEnvironment.reinitializeFormComponents();`. I thought the validation will also be triggered after I have chosen the directory without clicking the next button like the description implicated to me. Is there another way to *reinitialize* the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the initialization script is just run once when the screen is shown. In your case, you would have to update the label text from your validation script of the directory chooser. You can access the label in this way:

```
((JLabel)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("123").
    getConfigurationObject()).setText("new text");
```

Comment: Hm, I wanted to avoid code duplication but at the moment this is the only way. This solution works for me. Maybe the reinitialization of this components could be a feature for the next version?

Comment: I've added it to our issue tracker